# Cannot boot ubuntu 16.04.3 with kernel version greater than 4.4.0-89

Tags: boot, 16.04, kernel, radeon, amd-graphics

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and after updating my kernel from 4.4.0-89-generic to 4.4.0-93 I could not boot my system anymore. I also tried with kernel 4.4.0-96 and 4.4.0-97 and it seems that I cannot boot with any kernel after 4.4.0-89. Basically, when I try to boot with the latest kernel I just get a black screen, no image or text is displayed at all, even after waiting for a long time.

This is a description of the hardware I have on my iMac: https://pastebin.com/JPExJNb1

This is the kernel log I obtained from a failed boot attempt: https://pastebin.com/UdtskHes

Any ideas of what might be happening and what I can do to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please specify your computer, - Brand name and model; 
- CPU; 
- RAM (size); 
- internal drive (size); 
- graphics chip/card; 
- wifi chip/card; 
This can help us help you. (I have no problems with 4.4.0-97-generic, but we have different computers. Someone else might know about your hardware.)

Comment: There might be problems with the graphics card, ATI RV730/M96-XT [Mobility **Radeon HD 4670**]. But there may be other problems because it is an **iMac**. I have no own experience of iMacs, but if you are lucky, someone who knows better will this and chip in to help. - **I am not good at reading log files**, also in this case there are other people who know better and might chip in to help. (I can see that there is a problem with the network manager. Maybe the new kernel and its network driver does not recognize the network chip/card.) Have you installed a proprietary driver for the network?